# Is there any ethical issue which prevents me from paying high quality authors monetary compensation, to agree to write papers with me?

Tags: publications, ethics, authorship

I've recently started a PhD.  I'm having trouble getting high impact authors to agree to write papers with me.  Is there any ethical issue which prevents me from paying high impact authors monetary compensation, to agree to write papers with me?  I of course will obey any and all paper writing requirements, such as both must substantially contribute, etc...

Also, my original intention is that the monetary payments would be fully disclosed before the transactions, to all relevant parties, including my University, supervisors, opposing side in the final PhD, etc...

I kind of do the same thing with my daughter.  I hire a tutor, but ask them to help provide her with the required knowledge, but require her to do any and all actual work.

Comment: Most academic authors that I know are not particularly motivated by money (at least, not the kind of money your average PhD student can afford to offer).

Comment: I'll throw in that if you have trouble getting high impact authors to co-author that probably means (1) they don't know/trust you, (2) your work is not high-impact, or (3) they are your competition. I'd work more on figuring these out if you want to boost your academic career, rather than relying on money.

Comment: If your work is sufficiently interesting, they should be willing to write papers with you without any compensation from you.

Comment: Why would a high-impact author write papers with a new PhD student, (except for their own PhD students, of course)? There aren't enough hours in the day to write papers with every student who comes along. Build up a reputation for producing high quality work (e.g., with your own advisor) and then high-quality researchers will want to work with you.

Comment: In my academic papers, everyone had to list the source of their financial support for that topic. But, your university should have a person who knows the answer for your institution which may be different than other institutions. If you haven't already showered your department secretary with bribes and gifts, this is a good opportunity to start that.

Comment: @ff524 naw man greed comes in all shapes and sizes

Comment: @gerrit biased people have to be paid to override their aversions

Comment: I signed up on this stackexchange just to inform you that many people, me included, won't justify buying credit and reputation in academia or anywhere else! Thank you for helping the world become even more distorted by dishonesty, greed, and politics.

Comment: I think, although I'm not sure and hence this isn't an answer, that a key issue here is that high-impact authors are usually quite free to work on anything they like. They're funded by some institution or grant that gives them considerable discretion in their research, and although they may have teaching or other fixed-time responsibilities, they will write whatever papers they think are the best use of their available time. Using payment to affect that decision will undercut people's assumptions about what the person thinks of the merit of the particular research (yours).

Comment: ... which still isn't to say it's necessarily unethical: after all if industry funds a particular research project then nobody is fooled into thinking the researcher would have worked on exactly the same thing had they not been funded. But it's certainly likely to make people angry, or to consider that if it wasn't improper then everyone would be charging PhD students for collaboration. Which they don't, and if you think they shouldn't charge then it's perhaps not proper to offer them payment either.

Comment: If this practice were allowed, what would stop high demand authors from being hired for many papers? I think it would end up driving their impact factors even higher and making the impact factor even worse to measure an author's quality, as well as labeling the high impact author as an author-for-hire, which would probably hurt their reputation more than the increased impact factor could help it.

Comment: The answers mostly focus on whether this meets various standards of ethics, but I think an important point is that, whether or not you think this is ethical, it simply *isn't done.*

Comment: People, in academia, would always be suspicious of you and your work.

Comment: @kundor  can happen http://jrichardstevens.com/articles/monastersky-ebay.pdf

Comment: To the OP: In his answer, Alexandros says that based on reading your LinkedIn profile, you are a ">50 year old CS professional serving on many CEO roles." If that is indeed the case, why do you want to get a PhD? I ask this because the reason you are getting a PhD may be atypical. If you were to explain your motivation, this would help us to better address your situation.

Comment: @user137: You make it sound like "high demand authors" were sitting idle and not producing any research output as long as they're not "hired for many papers". Participating in a paper in a meaningful way takes a fair amount of time, and there are only so many papers you can work on in any given amount of time.

Comment: @ff524: I agree that most high quality co-authors would not be motivated by money ..., however I only need to find one motivated co-author.   Perhaps I have more money than the average PhD student.  Even if I was average, the normal PhD student rate for Harvard, is about 50,000 USD/year.  By going to a University with no tuition, perhaps I can cut out the middle man (Harvard), and I'll have 200K to pay the same Harvard professors.  (I of course understand all the other advantages of Harvard).  So I don't think lack of money is always an issue.

Comment: @che_kid: (1) yes, I was hoping, by paying money, I could get higher quality authors to get to know me.

Comment: @David Richerby: thx but I'm interested in writing extra papers which are not required (or counted), on a slightly different topic, as compared to my advisor.  It is not always true, they don't have time.  From time to time even high quality co-authors end up unemployed.  During that time, perhaps they will have enough hours in the day, to co-author with PhD students who don't have access to Harvard quality co-authors.

Comment: @Boyko Perfanov: see above, students already pay, at Harvard, 50,000 USD / year to work with high quality authors.  I was just thinking of cutting out the middle man.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: thx but even if people were suspicious, because I paid a high quality co-author, since there is a peer review process, and since a higher quality co-author signed his/her name, perhaps less people would be less suspicious.  Even if they were still suspicious, my consideration was to work with higher quality co-authors, and then with my new knowledge, write papers on my own.  If they were suspicious, they could then simply judge me, on my own papers and ignore all paid co-author papers.

Comment: @user137: Great reflection, "If this practice were allowed"!  However, to the extent that this practice should not be allowed, there should be some kind of a "generally accepted PhD student code of ethics".  (Maybe a non-profit organization).  I'm not aware of any (other than at each University).

Comment: @user2379888: If they are suspicious, then they can always ignore all my paid co-author papers.  Then then can judge me on the merit, of my own solo papers.

Comment: @I Like to Code: As you asked, my interesting background, to be over 50 and go for a PhD follows.  My Swedish University had a major issue trying to find a teacher for a computer networking class.  They hired me, on a temp. contract.  During my first year teaching, I won the University teacher of the year award.  The University requires a PhD to be hired on a permanent employment contract (for teaching).  So I decided to study for a PhD.  My most recent two papers that I co-authored, were in 2012 (before my MSc) and averaged 10 citations per paper (Google Scholar).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you are simply writing scientific papers, I don't think it is inherently wrong about hiring a collaborator. I do it all the time when I offer a student an RAship to work on a project and the student ends up as a co-author. It's a bit unusual that the student would be paying the professor, but I don't think there's an *ethical* problem there. (And in fact I do know of a few cases where a well-off individual has worked out an arrangement of this sort, albeit with a postdoc rather than someone more senior.) The only ethical issue I can see is that if the authors are required to disclosure their funding, the hired author might have to disclose that you had provided the funding. My student RAs always do so, after all -- we acknowledge the grant that supported them.

If the work is to be part of your thesis, things get more complicated. You would want to be very clear that you had not violated any university requirements for the preparation of the thesis. My gut feeling is that paying high-impact coauthors to help with the chapters crosses a line, but I can't nail it down to some particular rule. And obviously (I hope), paying anyone on your PhD committee would almost certainly create a conflict of interest that would be a significant breach of ethics.

All of that said, there most definitely is a *reputational* issue here. Word will get out that you are paying people to collaborate. Depending on your goals, this may not be in your advantage.

Comment: +1 for mentioning reputation. In my field (and probably many, many fields), a person hiring/paying a senior researcher would certainly be treated with disdain and not be good for one's career.

Comment: @che_kid typically jrs allow seniors to coop thier research as thier own using aggrandization as payment. those senors or fellow jr's who show disdain for offering compensation which isn't first or contact authorship are not really worth the trouble.

Answer (score 93):

I think the other answers are way too nice. As for myself, I have never heard of such a insulting / distorted idea about what a PHD is. Do you want to buy yourself a PHD? There are countless diploma mills for that, so you could hang a useless paper on your wall to claim you have a PHD without doing all the necessary work / research yourself. Do you want to buy yourself an academic career by hiring established professors to write papers for and with you? That is even more insulting. If that was the case, every rich kid could tell his / her dad. "I want a PHD for Christmas. Buy me some high impact authors to write papers with me. Pleaaase..".

It does not work that way. And the fact that you are at the beginning of your PHD and you are even considering this, is even more infuriating for people who have busted their behinds to get a PHD (and some of the people in Academia SE still do to this day). Reconsider why you want a PHD and what you want a PHD for. I am mostly sure you want it for the all the wrong reasons and not because you actually want to do research. In that case, you should probably spare yourself the agony, because without a passion for research your PHD road will be a long, rocky one.

**UPDATE**: In retrospect, the tone of my answer is pretty hostile. Still, the upvotes showed that my initial reaction to the OP's question also expressed an important part of the Academia SE community. In this sense, my answer might still be useful if it makes the OP reconsider his "thought" of hiring "high-impact" authors to write papers with him, since such an action will probably cause much more damage to him than my "harsh" words.

Moreover, since we had a previous question about "Is it ethical to hire a programmer for ... my CS PHD" and now "Is it ethical to hire high-impact authors ... to write papers with me", I sincerely hope that in the future we do not get any other questions like "Is it ethical to hire a professor to write my PHD thesis if I still do the typesetting in Latex and all spell checking" or "Is it ethical to hire a professor to do my PHD defence, since I will still bring the pizza and the drinks".

Comment: Don't confuse published research with the thesis.

Comment: @briandfoy In my discipline (CS) without published research there is no thesis. And most theses there are "stapler" and basically present what you wrote on the papers. So, there is no confusion on my part.

Comment: This is really rude and insensitive

Comment: Not only is this rude, but you seem to assume a bit much here. Assuming that he simply want to buy a PHD is a bit much. The OP explicitly stated " I of course will obey any and all paper writing requirements, such as both must substantially contribute, etc..."  I agree that the student may not understand "the point" of a PHD, but tearing him to shreds doesn't help him, and only makes you look rude.

Comment: @Eric If you look at the LinkedIn profile of the OP (which I did before answering - did you?) the OP is a >50 year old CS professional serving on many CEO roles. So, give him some credit that he can handle harsh criticism. I am trying to protect him from doing such a horrible mistake, because the academia world is not the corporate "if we can't do it ourselves, hire someone that can" world. Also, the "tutor" addition to his question shows his obvious misunderstanding. He already has a tutor (his supervisor) ...

Comment: ...(continued) and he has the capacity to learn from all those "high-impact" authors by simply reading their papers. But he must be the one to come up with the way to extend them and learn how to write a high-impact paper from simply reading many of them and consulting his supervisor, instead of hiring "tutors".

Comment: Hang on, PhD students often *collaborate* with co-authors on papers that they publish prior to their thesis. Nevertheless, they do the necessary work and research for themselves. They aren't saying "Pleeeease, I want a PhD for nothing at all", are they? Suppose the questioner pays the collaborator, and *also* contributes just as much to the paper as a typical PhD student?

Comment: @SteveJessop Sorry to have to break it to you but as a wild analogy,  dating a woman and paying a woman to "date" you is not the same thing. It is the payment that makes the difference and not the hours or the effort you spend at the "date".

Comment: Then I guess the question is whether the PhD is awarded for persuading women to date you, or awarded for dressing smartly and eating at fancy restaurants. If it's for the work, then it *is* the hours you spend on the date (and the quality of the output) that the PhD committee will judge, and not why your date was there with you or how desirable she is. Perhaps it's for both things, although PhD students aren't *explicitly* assessed for how high-impact their co-authors are as a condition of awarding the degree.

Comment: People complaining that Alexandros was "mean" are ridiculous.  Perhaps he should have put a "Trigger Warning" on his post.  The OP isn't saying he isn't able to get published, it's that because he's junior, his stuff doesn't get as much attention.  Welcome to the club.  Most PhD students, and even junior faculty, are not high profile.  Part of the career is working for it.  I wouldn't respect someone who bought his way up the ladder.

Comment: Universities pay famous non-academics (CEO's, actors, musicians, athletes, etc.) and grant them professorships just so the school can advertise that they have so and so on the faculty. These professors rarely if ever teach a single class. How could they when they are touring with their band or filming a movie? Television commercials have historically paid well known personalities endorse their products. Why is it wrong for a PhD student to align themself with and pay a well known........

Comment: .........researcher to co-author a paper? It seems more unethical for the "expert" have their grad assistants and students conduct research and take full credit for the work. @corvus below does it the correct way.

Comment: This isn't overly hostile. It is spot on. If a PhD candidate is this clueless about what academia is, he needs to be told sooner rather than later.

Comment: @JJLL It's wrong for a PhD student to pay for co-authors because it undermines the integrity of the academic profession. The purpose of getting published is to further the academic field first, and demonstrate one's dedication to the field and intellectual merit second. Collaboration is an implicit peer agreement that someone has worked hard for the right for their ideas to be recognized. Paying for that right throws all merit into question, and skews everything the system stands on. It's akin to buying grades on an exam, or paying for desired results on a drug test.

Comment: @JJLL There is a huge difference between paying someone for commercials and paying someone for what is supposed to be a non for profit collaboration. As for your last point, with all due respect arguments of the type "this is OK because there is an even bigger problem" are junk.

Comment: @Alexandros Point well taken. I hadn't  realized is business background.

Comment: @NickS. Actually, there isn't. Switching ethics as it suits is what is junk. Universities give professorships to well known people so they can claim them as  faculty to lure students.  The "professors" rarely if ever teach a class. A well respected university near me claimed an Oscar Awarding winning actor and world-class classical violinist as their own. Neither taught because........they were acting and performing. In this case, if you read what the OP wrote, is in no way shape or form dishonest. He CLEARLY stated that he would reveal all to the school. He also stated that HE was going to

Comment: conduct the research. So again, how is that different than hiring an actor to represent your product even though you researched and developed it, marketed it, distributed it, etc. How different is it from schools that "hire" high profile celebrities who never teach to enhance the legitamacy of their faculty. And by the way, it is a fallacy of logic to reject an idea because one element may be wrong or because a person (like me) can't articulate as well as another. Peace.

Comment: @JJLL I have never run into the issue you mention, and I think it is usually not done in my area. But I can see how in other departments this could be done. Anyhow, the question i have for you is the following: in your opinion is it ethical for Universities to do that?

Comment: @NickS.   Hey Nick. Good question. My comments were offered as an example of how universities behave.  If it is universally acceptable/ethical  for professors to use paid graduate assistants to conduct research and only the professor's name goes on the publication, then how much more or less acceptable/ethical is a student doing the research and paying a professor to claim co-authorship. Yes, I understand the directionality, professor to student, student to professor.  I don't have the answer Nick but, at least on the surface, it seems hypercritical to accept one but not the other

Comment: Don't know how legite the site is but check-out Professors  Oprah Winfrey and Jesse Ventura:  http://www.earnmydegree.com/education-resources/career-info/7-celebrities-who-have-taught-as-college-professors/.     New York Magazine: http://nymag.com/news/intelligencer/topic/celebrity-professors-2013-1/. And huffingtonpress:  http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/01/07/celebrity-professors-whic_n_805542.html

Comment: @JJLL What do you mean by "It is universally acceptable ..."? Again you use examples of unethical behavior, as it is the norm. Doing that is unfortunately happening in some fields, but again your examples are unethical and many if not most professors disapprove. Yes there are some unethical universities and some unethical profs, but you are generalizing. And I, and most profs I know, don't accept either, how does that make me hypocritical?   As for the articles, these are exceptions, not the norm...

Comment: @NickS.  I agree with you Nick. I always worked independently and whatever my grades they were my grades. But I am not certain that these behaviors are not more common than you think.  And to be fair, aren't you also generalizing when you say "most professors"?  The original poster obviously (?) is highly ethical or else he would not have asked his question. It is my understanding that "ethics" is quite complex. Does acting in such-and-such manner hurt anyone physically or mentally? Is it illegal? Does it violate norms? Does the section violate, say in this case, the universities policy ......

Comment: ......on research and plagiarism? Will the action provide an unfair advantage or disadvantage? We don't know where the poster attends school so we can't fully understand the standards of that culture. I would like to know who would agree to the OP's proposal. Would that possibly harm their reputation? In that case, it would be unethical because of the potential harm to the "experts" reputation. Once again Nick, I essentially agree with you, I just like looking at situations from different perspectives. This originates from me always trying to do the right thing and being told "don't look....

Comment: ......at the other guy." I have realized late in life that doing the right thing is innate to me, but I am no longer convinced that it is always practical. Perhaps this realization comes from the fact that I hold a doctorate and work outside an academic setting. Book knowledge is not always the same as real-world knowledge. For example, if the OP asks university administrators his question, he may receive a different response than the book publisher which sells the text books used by his university.

Comment: @JJLL You misquoted me I didn't say "most professors" which would be a generalization, I said "many if not most" and especially  "most professors I know". It is true thought that in my field, mathematics, this type of issues don't appear as often as in other areas. In mathematics it is hard to fake research, and it is much more rare for students to make research, and profs just to add their names on the paper. It does happen, but from my experience the community dissaproves. Again, the point I am trying to make is that one should not start any argument with "this is less worse/unethical than".

Comment: I agree with the statements given here. I have been down the rocky road of relying on a crutch to obtain an inappropriate grade. It's much easier for me to just do the work myself; then I not only have the knowledge that I am capable of conducting the applicably necessary effort, but moreover I have learned the skills necessary to ensure successful results.

Comment: @JJLL: they never actually called them "Professors" Oprah Winfrey and Jesse Ventura. You don't need a PhD (or even any credential) in order to have some useful real-world knowledge worth teaching. Steve Jobs and Bill Gates are college dropouts, etc. http://articles.chicagotribune.com/1999-05-19/business/9905190198_1_stedman-graham-kellogg-oprah-winfrey

Comment: But no one is on the more interesting point: If I pay someone to work with me, and at the end of the day I didn't really make any significant contribution, is the other person going to point that out and take all the credit? Is he going to refund me my money? Come on, this won't happen. What happened is that I just bought a Phd. Nice!

Comment: I think @Alexandros understood OP as "*I want others to do work instead of me*", while what I think OP meant is "*I want **my** work to be taken more seriously*". Therefore Alexandros' fury is both understandable and out of place.

Comment: @Alexandros: I didn't say, "write papers for and with you".  I only said write papers with me (co-author).  As I said in the comments, to my question, Harvard students are already asking their dads for 50,000 / year, because they want to work with high quality co-authors.  I'm just cutting out the middle man.

Comment: @caseyr547: It does appear rude and insensitive, however this is exactly the type of feedback I really like.  I don't always think from all perspectives and Alexandros (and 77 others) have really helped me look at the situation, in a new way.

Comment: @JJLL: You mention that it is more unethical for the "expert".  I thought the same.  However, high quality authors would not risk their reputation being unethical, so I was assuming that, in general, the high quality author would act as the police, and make sure that I contributed substantially to the paper.  If I didn't contribute, I should write in the agreement, that they get to keep all of the money, and I have no right to dispute it.

Comment: @CodeMoose: You mention "Collaboration is an implicit peer agreement that someone has worked hard for the right for their ideas to be recognized".  To the extent that Harvard's students can more easily access high quality co-authors, it appears that there is not equal opportunity (for the students who can't pay 50,0000 / year).  So I don't think it is always unethical, under all circumstances, for someone to pay the minimum, to have equal access to the same high quality co-authors.

Comment: @Ant: I don't agree, that the money would never be refunded.  To get around your valid point, I could simply put in the agreement, that if I don't substantially contribute to the paper, they can keep the money.  I could also agree never to see them in person or talk on the phone (and make all our email correspondence public).

Comment: @ToddBooth. Your Harvard 50,000$ argument is invalid. Tuition fees are for undergraduate education. Contrary, PHDs are usually funded, so you cannot just buy your way to a PHD in Harvard and buying access to "high-quality" authors. Also, USA <> Entire World. There are many high-quality European (probably Asian as well) public universities without tuition that produce high-quality research.

Comment: @Alexandros: The Harvard PhD education is about 50,000 USD/year tuition.  Thx!, I now see that some fellowships, will cover the tuition and fees.  You said "argument is invalid" ... "PHDs are usually funded".  For the other case (not funded, PhD student pays full tuition), do you think my argument is valid?

Comment: @ToddBooth, you would be hard pressed to find many self-funded PhD students at the top tier American universities in STEM fields.  If the school admits someone without funding, that means no one there was interested enough in the applicant to want to support them.  Why would you go to a place where you were only wanted for your tuition dollars?  Many places won't even admit unfunded students for this reason.  I challenge you to find a single faculty member, anywhere, who self-funded his PhD education.

Comment: @user237988: Your comment was very helpful.  My original question was based on my incorrect assumption, that most all USA PhD students paid a very high tuition.  Thx so much!  It must be very hard to get in, so the students should be very proud.

Answer (score 25):

> Is there any ethical issue which prevents me from paying high impact authors monetary compensation, to agree to write papers with me?

Assuming you are honest and open about what you are doing, and you don't violate any of the usual ethical rules about collaboration and authorship, I doubt you can get in any trouble for doing this.

However, your collaborators might get in trouble if they accept your proposal.  If they are already being paid to do this work, then their employer or funding agency will be unhappy to hear that they are making side deals for extra money, so you'll have to be careful in how this is set up.  Furthermore, being paid by a student to collaborate looks terrible, since it suggests they are exploiting you or extorting money from you.  Even if they insist it was your idea, I'm sure administrators will be unhappy with them.

In any case, this would be bad for everyone's reputation, as Corvus pointed out at the end of his answer.  You'd effectively be announcing that you can't convince people to work with you without offering them money, and your collaborators would be announcing that they sold out and decided to earn money via a project they wouldn't otherwise consider worth their time.  Unless you work in a field with an exceptionally strong commercial ethos, neither side would end up looking good.

Instead of offering money, it's worth rethinking how you are trying to attract collaborators.  For example, are you trying to recruit people to work on your own ideas?  That can be a tough sell, since they probably have lots of exciting projects already taking up their time (otherwise you wouldn't be interested in them in the first place), and they have little idea of how skilled you are or how good your ideas are.  Instead, you might start by seeing whether you could contribute in some way to their current projects.  If you impress them by doing so, then they may be much more open to other ideas you have.

Comment: "their employer or funding agency will be unhappy to hear that they are making side deals for extra money" That is not necessarily true: the last (UK) academic job description I read in detail explicitly said that the person was allowed to spend up to X weeks a year on external consultancy without needing specific permission. As I recall, when applying for a UK research grant, you state what fraction of their time the PI will spend on the grant. That's usually less than 100%, to allow for teaching, which allows scope for side projects. (But +1 for the rest of the answer.)

Comment: @Anonymous Mathematicia: Wow, your  comment really helped me!!! rethink ... attract collaborators ... own ideas  ... tough sell ... contribute to their current projects.  I had not tried that and I'm sure I'll have a much better chance with your great strategy!!!

Answer (score 19):

If you are lining their pocket with a secret bribe, then of course it is wrong on several levels. If you are offering to hire them in an openly declared consulting role on a problem, and willing to pay their rate and deal with the appropriate paperwork, that's more plausible.  Note, however, that anybody actually high quality is likely to have a consulting rate in excess of $200/hour, and you probably can't afford them.

Comment: Especially since a decent research paper is going to need at least 100 hours of work.

Answer (score 10):

Luckily, there is no genuine issue here, since, I'd wager, none of the people you'd fancy paying to collaborate would do so, even for significant sums of money. This is lucky for you, since if any such thing happened there'd arise many problems... first about whether you earned a Ph.D., second, about your own fitness for the academic milieu...

So, in brief, don't do it, don't try it. Even a failed attempt would be so operationally unfortunate for you that the ethical issue wouldn't even get to the front of the queue.

Answer (score 8):

**TLDR** You can hire researchers to work with you,
but you still need to do independent work for your PhD thesis.

I am unsure if you understand what is the typical research process
for a PhD student.

Based on my observations of my PhD classmates,
I would say that this is a more or less typical PhD experience
in an applied math PhD program:

- A student would have a professors as his/her PhD adviser,
  and meet the adviser approximately once every one or two weeks.
  (Some students have two PhD co-advisers but the process is similar.)
- The adviser would give high-level input such as:
  why don't you read this paper,
  can we build a mathematical model of this problem?
  The student would do the work,
  and discuss his/her findings with the adviser during the next meeting.
- At the end of about two or three years,
  the student would write the paper,
  with the adviser providing some feedback.
- After 4-6 years, the student writes a thesis
  which is basically stapling 2-3 of his/her research papers together.

In our field, basically the student does all the tedious work,
while the adviser provides high-level guidance.

I think that it is basically impossible
to hire anyone to do your PhD work for you
because **you are awarded a PhD
when you can demonstrate through your independent work
that you are capable of independent research.**
(Caveat: Among my classmates,
occassionally one of the 3 chapters of their thesis
was joint work with a fellow PhD student.
Nevertheless, at least the other 2 chapters were his/her independent work.)

Finally, perhaps your expectations are unrealistic.
I think it is fair to say that in almost any field,
most PhD students do not co-author a paper
with a professor in the top 1% of their field
during the course of their PhD studies.
You don't have to co-author a paper with a famous professor
in order to do excellent work.
In fact, if you do co-author a paper with a famous professor,
people might discount your contribution to the paper
because they think
"This is just another one of Professor X's amazing ideas
that Todd Booth just latched on to."
This thinking would be further reinforced
if they found out that you paid for the collaboration
as this is extremely unusual in academia
for a co-author to be paying another co-author out-of-pocket.
(Usually funding comes through grants and not personal funds.)

Instead of trying to pay a famous professor to work with you,
why not work to become a famous professor in your own right?
If you do excellent work and become known for it,
it is extremely likely that chances will arise
for you to work with other famous professors.

Comment: @i like to code.  Hello Coder. Is it possible that people would question the expert thinking he had a student do all the work and he took credit for it? Why would he (or she) need a student collaborator?

Comment: From my understanding (others can confirm or deny this), when a paper is written by a professor and a PhD student(s), people expect that the PhD student(s) did most of the tedious work while the professor provided high-level guidance. This doesn't mean that the professor's contribution is less important, just that it is different from the student's contribution.

Comment: @i like to code. But are you sure it isn't the professor who gets the credit. Do the students get credit as co-authors. I really don't know.

Comment: @I Like to Code: You wrote, "if you do co-author a paper with a famous professor, people might discount your contribution".  Great reflection and extremely helpful.  My new plan is to get someone, just a little bit higher quality than me.  You wrote, "hire anyone to do your PhD work".  If I worked with a high quality co-author, I would assume their standard is higher, and I would in fact, do much more work (and learn more) than with a lower quality co-student.

Comment: @JJLL From my understanding, all of the authors get recognition for a jointly published paper. How much "credit" a student author gets may depend on how the professor speaks about the student. For example, if the professor says, "This student was extremely creative and hardworking and it is really his/her work, with minimal contributions from me" then other researchers would have a much higher estimation of the student's ability.

Comment: @ToddBooth Based on what you said about your situation, I am wondering why you feel the need to write a paper with a famous professor. If your goal is to take the job at your Swedish university, isn't a PhD from a "good enough" school sufficient? Does it make a difference whether you got a PhD from a top-5 vs a top-100 school?

Comment: @ToddBooth It is hard to say what is the best type of collaborator for you. Working with a fellow student or less famous professor may mean that you get more time and more help, but when working with a famous or more senior professor, you might get better guidance but less help. You have to figure out what is better for you.

Comment: @I Like to Code, As I understand, my PhD can even be from a top-1000 school.  However, I have a passion to learn and I thought it would help by working with the top% of authors.  Thx for the helpful comment that, by working with authors who are not in the top%, they will have more time to help me.  So I'll start lower and try hard to work my way to the top% (via hard work) without payments.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the same as hiring a tutor.  I suppose its possible that you could find a retired or semi-retired academic who is interested in your work.  That said, the usual course of action is for you to find a researcher to work for or with, and write your own paper with their advice (and their name on your paper so you can publish).  I don't know what your field of study is, but the route you are suggesting doesn't sound like it will help you get grant funding in the future.

I think the problem you are having is related to the expense of running a research laboratory, and the way researchers are judged by their peers.  I am not a researcher, but I have had a front row seat for my lab's struggle for research funding - so here is some perspective.

The cost of running a research lab can be huge.  For instance, the cost for some types of microscopes can easily be 6 figures.  And the yearly maintenance contract for a microscope can be 5 figures.  And of course most labs employ lab technicians and/or post-docs.  On top of this, research groups pay their university a percentage of some of their expenses - salaries and some purchases.  For a "wet" lab, this is almost 50%.  In other words, a researcher's time has to equal a lot of money.

So a lab has to get some grants, and researchers must have published research in order to get those grants.  An experiment with negative results, even important and valuable negative results, generally cannot be published.  So successful, accepted research is the indirect source of almost 100% of the funding of many labs.  Sound like a crapshoot?  Yes it is.  Encourages bias?  Ah hum mumble.  Do researchers generally give into this bias?  I think most of them try very hard not to.

The grants that a lab receives are peer reviewed - that is researchers are on each other's grant panels.  Researchers cannot afford to be involved in a research project unless they can defend it.  Research can be highly specialized, and this makes it difficult to defend against critics who are experts in something slightly different.  Researchers I know always hope to get panel members who do very similar work - if not, they are likely to get turned down.

There is a lot of pressure put on researchers, and they value their time and reputation highly.  Unless you can substantially contribute to funding a lab or have a project which the researcher really understands and believes in, they won't risk working for you.  And there's no denying that there can be a status thing here - they would rather work with you then for you.

http://www.nature.com/jcbfm/journal/v30/n7/full/jcbfm201051a.html
http://acfnewsource.org.s60463.gridserver.com/science/negative_results.html

Comment: Thx for the incredibly helpful comments.  I now plan to do the following.  I'll look for co-authors, who need papers concerning their funded projects, and where I can use my skills to help them, on their ideas.  This will be much, much easier than what I've been doing, which was to get co-authors to work with me, on my projects, which have no funding.  Instead of trying to get the top high quality co-authors, I'll shoot for co-authors who have higher quality than me, but not so much higher.

Comment: This sounds like a much more effective approach.  Good luck!!

Answer (score 2):

You say you have "recently started a Ph.D."  At that stage, you're only expected to be gaining your bearings in the field the Ph.D. is about.  You shouldn't jump ahead of yourself.

Typically, your connections with other researchers will come from your advisor at this stage.  Later, as you learn more about the field, you will develop more independent relationships with other researchers based on your level of scholarship.

In many fields, it is common for top Ph.D. candidates not to publish until towards the end of the graduate program, after they have actually produced valuable research.  The research tends to define the authorship, not the other way around.

Furthermore, single-authored papers are arguably more prestigious than those with collaborators, all else being equal, because they reflect a higher level of intellectual independence.  Caveat: Single authored papers are only possible in some fields.

Comment: The relative prestige of single-author papers varies from field to field. In my own field (theoretical computer science), single-author papers are rather rare and I've not noticed anyone attach extra prestige to them.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it would be unethical to do this, as it would mean that students or researchers from richer backgrounds would have an unfair advantage over those from more working class backgrounds. In some ways it could be seen to parallel the idea of unpaid internships which give an automatic head start to young people from richer backgrounds who have the freedom to focus on obtaining key skills relevant to their desired career, while others have to take whichever paying job that allows them to subsist themselves/ their families.

Comment: You don't know anything about the posters background, and >50 year olds usually don't rely on their parents money. I would assume that he worked hard to make money, and has the right to spend it however he likes.

Comment: @gnasher729 How do you define entitlement? A person can work very hard for many years as a cleaner or in some other low paid job, reach their 50's and have nothing to show in monetary terms for all their many years of hard labour. Why should someone who has had the good fortune to have obtained a high paid job or perhaps who has not had dependants to provide for (regardless of whether they're hard working or not) be more entitled to such perks that give them an advantage over their less well off peers? I think the perception that some are more "entitled" than others is a malady in the world.

Answer (score 0):

Taking this question seriously, since you appear to be independently wealthy, you could establish a research foundation (The Booth Foundation) and announce grants in your particular area of interest. I still doubt that you will get listed as a co-author but your foundation will at least get an acknowledgment.

Or you could set up your own own research institute, in which case you might get courtesy last author depending on your field.

Neither option guarantees that anyone serious will actually want to work with you, but you might attract some mercenaries or cranks. Cf. [Discovery Institute](http://www.discovery.org/).

Ps Neither of these will get you anywhere near a PhD at a reputable university.